# jQuery - Mouseleave after timeout, where is pointer

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out a way to know where the mousepointer is (like over which element) after I've done a mouseleave AND a timeout.

Is there some easy way to get this?

I've done a jsfiddle on how my code look-ish like:
https://jsfiddle.net/0Lwxhh8r/

HTML

```
<div class="showTooltip"></div>
<div class="showTooltip"></div>
<div class="showTooltip"></div>
<div class="showTooltip"></div>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

CSS

```
.showTooltip {
height: 70px;
width: 50px;
border: 1px solid #000;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px 10px;
}
#tooltip {
position: fixed;
width: 400px;
height: 240px;
border: 1px solid #000;
display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on({
mouseenter: function (e) {
        $("#tooltip").show();
},
mouseleave: function (e) {
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Where is mousepointer?");
    $("#tooltip").hide();
}, 500)
}
}, ".showTooltip");
```

So I kind of want to know, if after the timeout, the mousepointer is at another .showTooltip, #tooltip or just somewhere else.

Comment: Sounds like a messy way to achieve something simple.

Comment: If there is a easier way, I am all ears!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a delayed hide.  Have you tried this:  on mouseenter show, on mouseleave set timeout, on mouseenter *cancel* timeout.   Then if the mouse if back over the element, the tooltip won't be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that @freedomn-m's "delayed hide" theory is correct, you can write :

```
var timeoutRef = null;

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
        $("#tooltip").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        timeoutRef = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#tooltip").hide();
        }, 500);
    }
}, ".showTooltip");
```

Alternatively, the ugly outer var can be avoided by storing the timeout reference as a `data` property of the `#tooltip` element.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        clearTimeout($("#tooltip").show().data('timoutRef'));
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        var $tooltip = $("#tooltip").data('timoutRef', setTimeout(function() {
            $tooltip.hide();
        }, 500));
    }
}, ".showTooltip");
```